# I have 2 divs horizontally inside outer div. When content of 2nd inner div goes long, it should wrap in its own div area

Tags: html, css

Outer div:
    InnerDiv1  InnerDiv2.

InnerDiv1 and InnerDiv2 are inside Outer div in line.

Now, if InnerDiv2's text goes long, then it should wrap and come down but starting point should be the 1st character of InnerDiv2.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .coverageDetailsOuterAHX {
     display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 2%;
        width: 317px;
        white-space:nowrap;                                                     
    }
    .coverageDetailsInnerAHX {
    display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 2%;
        white-space:nowrap;                             
    }
    .coverageDetailsAHX{
    display: inline-block;
         float:none;
        margin-right: 2%;
        white-space:wrap;                                        
   }
   </style>
   </head>
    <body>
         <div class= "coverageDetailsOuterAHX">
            <div class= "coverageDetailsInnerAHX">
                <p>All Coverage Details.</p>
            </div>
        <div class= "coverageDetailsAHX" > 
            <p>Learn more about CareFirst. Text is longer. Can accomodate 
            more characters.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result should be:

```
All Coverage Details. Learn more about.CareFirst. Text is longer. Can
                      accomodate more characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.coverageDetailsOuterAHX {
  display: flex;
}

.coverageDetailsOuterAHX div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.coverageDetailsInnerAHX {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverageDetailsOuterAHX">

  <div class="coverageDetailsInnerAHX">

    <p>All Coverage Details.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="coverageDetailsAHX">

    <p>Learn more about CareFirst. Text is longer. Can accomodate more characters.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What should be the display for other divs? What I have to remove from my code?

Comment: Actually, with flex , there is 1 problem. There is 1 small image icon before text of both divs using span tab. And these texts are basically clickable links. So, on clicking "All Coverage Details" it shifts to right and overlaps with icon of 2nd div..

Comment: Sounds like the basis of **another** question since you did not mention this issue at the time.